# trying to separate the string and insert it in a different position

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

does anyone know how to separate this string and put it in base_url in a different position like this:

```
movie = ("Burning 2018")
base_url = ("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+(Burning)+"&y="+(2018)+"&apikey=")
```

This is my code:

```
movie = ("Burning 2018")
base_url = ("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+Burning+"&y="+2018+"&apikey=")
r = (requests.get(base_url))
b = r.json()
print(b)
```

Comment: Why are you enclosing everything in parentheses?

Comment: @Nick sorry is that a mistake? I'm new in learning python

Comment: Parentheses are not required in general, mostly they are used when you need to enforce a particular evaluation order for example `a = (b + c)/d`. They don't have any negative effect though, other than making the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import urllib.parse

title, year = movie.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    "t": title,
    "y": year,
    "apikey": ""
})
base_url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?" + query_string
```

[rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.rsplit) splits the `movie` starting from the **right** side of the string. `maxsplit=1` tells it to only split once, to handle cases where the movie title contains spaces.

[urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) builds a query string using the keys and values in the provided dict. This handles cases where the movie title contains spaces, punctuation, or other special characters.

Comment: this is the answer i need from yesterday,,you are a hero,i really appreciate this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can [reverse split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) your `movie` variable on space, with a maximum of 1 split, to generate the title and year. Then use an [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to generate the `base_url`:

```
movie = 'Burning 2018'
title, year = movie.rsplit(' ', 1)
base_url = f"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={title}&y={year}&apikey="
print(base_url)
```

Output:

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Burning&y=2018&apikey=
```

By using reverse split, the code will still work when a movie has more than one word in the title e.g.

```
movie = 'Lord of the Rings 2004'
title, year = movie.rsplit(' ', 1)
base_url = f"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={title}&y={year}&apikey="
print(base_url)
```

Output:

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Lord of the Rings&y=2004&apikey=
```

Comment: This is really a perfect answer and it goes well, my learning is fun!, I really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
title = movie.split()
base_url = ("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+title[0]+"&y="+title[1]+"&apikey=")
```

Comment: I am sorry i have typo index at title[2] i mean that title[1]
[read this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) about split strings in python

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Your answer would benefit from some elaboration. Also, you should take the opportunity to remove the extraneous parentheses the OP has used.

Comment: This works well if the title is only one word,,,what if the title has multiple words?
thank you for answering

Answer (score -1):

f-strings

```
question_id_no = input("What question id are you searching for?")
f"https://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{question_id_no}"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, nor does it offer the elaboration that should be present in a good answer.